# linq to entity with many to many relationship

Tags: linq-to-entities, many-to-many

i have 2 tables rol and users
and the rolUsers table with IdUser and IdRol 
   public List SeeRolFromXUser(int Iduser)//
        {

```
        List<string> lisrRP = new List<string>();
        var query = from u in contextoBD.Users
                    where u.IdUsers== Iduser
                    select u.Roles;//i had to do that but that returns an entity collection i´ dont know haw to get the rol from an x user
        foreach (var r in query)
        {
            lisrRP.Add(r.ToString());
        }

        return lisrRP;

    }
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a question.  I'm not sure what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps you, you may do:

```
Roles MyUsersRole = (from  R in contextoBD.Roles 
                where R.IdUsers== Iduser        
                select R).SingleOrDefault();  

if (MyUsersRole == null) {
    return;  
}
```

`SingleOrDefault()` expects one single value otherwise it sets the default to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

i did it like that ,and it works

```
        var query = from u in  contextoBD.Usuarios
                    where u.IdUsuario == Idusuario
                    select u;

        List<Role> b = new List<Role>();

        foreach (var r in query)
        {
          b.AddRange(r.Roles);
        }

        return b;
```